# I can't create any type of network with neutron

Tags: openstack

I'm Rookie for openstack, I want to create a network with neutron now. But it always show me it fails.

This is my  neutron-linuxbridge-agent.log
[image]

Comment: Looks like rabbit is not happy. Those error messages are related to rabbitmq.

Comment: i check my Configuration file,but i don't find error

Answer (score 0):

i see neturon.server.log a error

INFO neutron.api.v2.resource [req-d2d242c1-7b1d-4ad3-a2e8-33d85dcc3ac3 f77a94713b74422fa45805fc91b6c907 380e5668659b4e8b99c66f6ec331aebf - - -] create failed (client error): Invalid input for operation: physical_network 'default' unknown  for VLAN provider network.

i find where is problem,because i'm set a wrong label,there is no label named 'default'

Comment: Hi @俊-Postgraduate, I am having similar type problem. Can you please elaborate how did you solve this ?